# data.table underperforming when applying function into nested fields

Tags: r, data.table

I wrote a function that applies another function into each nested field in a data.table:

```
n <- 3000
nameslist <- paste0("NAME",1:n)
dt <- data.table(name_var = nameslist
                    , value_var = rnorm(1e7)
                    , car_color = c("B","B","B","G","G","G","G"))
dt <- dt[,.(.(.SD)), by = name_var] # nesting dt and finishing toy data creation

transform_value <- function(x, fun, campo, ...) {  
     x [, match.fun (fun)(get(campo), ...)] }

system.time({
dt[, min_value:=lapply(V1, transform_value, "min", "value_var")
]})
```

This runs correctly and pretty fast, it takes about .36 seconds in my machine for `n <- 3000`.

However when I make `n <- 500000` (nameslist length 500,000 long), it takes 217 seconds!

Thus it seems that data.table is not effectivelly optimized by the code I wrote in the loop 
`dt[, min_value:=lapply(V1, transform_value, "min", "value_var")`. My take is that there is an overhead each time data.table enters into each instance of a nested loop, but I am not sure.

What can I do to make it run faster?

Comment: The timing is for the assign line which does not have a ```by``` argument. Could you clarify whether ```dt[, .(.(.SD)), by = name_var]``` is slow or whether the ```transform_value``` is slow?

Comment: Like Cole said, you are just looping by row with `lapply`, I don't really see where is the `by` arg blame.

Comment: @Cole, the slowness is in the transform_value loop, not in dt[, .(.(.SD)), by = name_var] loop.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, I edited the question, it is clearer now, thank you.

Comment: Again, as I understand it, you are running by row in an nested data.table while each row is another pretty big data.table while you are applying a function on it. data.table/data.frame weren't designed to operate by row. Instead, you should avoid nesting your data set and instead, apply your function on whole groups. Also, `get` is pretty memory intense. You could simply do `dt[, min(value_var), by = name_var]` on your original `dt` (before you nested it). If you have some more complicated function, just predefine it and then use like above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are interested by performance, you should definitely set a primary key. Once paid the fixed cost of setting the key (which means a reordering of your rows in contiguous memory slots), you will experience significant gains.

Taking again your example

```r
dt <- data.table(name_var = nameslist
                 , value_var = rnorm(1e7)
                 , car_color = c("B","B","B","G","G","G","G"))
dt2 <- data.table::copy(dt)
setkeyv(dt2, c("name_var"))

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  dt[,.(.(.SD)), by = name_var],
  dt2[,.(.(.SD)), by = name_var],
  times = 20L
)

Unit: milliseconds
                            expr       min        lq     mean    median       uq      max neval
  dt[, .(.(.SD)), by = name_var] 658.76452 676.22905 706.3578 699.46644 727.8368 793.1192    20
 dt2[, .(.(.SD)), by = name_var]  91.62276  92.48002 131.2777  99.15238 135.1332 318.3719    20
```

Just for this step, in my laptop (that is not very fast), you see a division by 7 of computation time (the order of magnitude can vary a lot)

Comment: Thank you @linog. Actually the loop that is slow is the one I measured the execution time and have the transform_value function in it.

Comment: Ah it's a different question in that case, sorry for the misunderstanding. This is not the `by` argument that is to blame. Maybe someone else will have a solution regarding this part of your code, I don't have one in mind.

Comment: that was all my fault, I was unclear in my qustion. Thank you.